# Convert a date in SQL from one format to multiple formats in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm taking SQL in school and am really new to it.  We are using Oracle APEX for school.  I need to write ONE query to convert a date into multiple formats.  I thought I could do this by writing the statement with a substitution variable so I could input what the new format would be, but it isn't working exactly right.  Below is my attempt at the one statement:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('04-Jan-2008', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), :xx) AS "Date"
 FROM dual;
```

When I click "Run", the variables box pops up,and I type in the below so that it shows as "January 4th, 2008".  I've tried it with and without quote marks.  "January 4th" shows up, but not the comma and the year.

```
 fmMonth ddth, YYYY
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Have you tried putting quotation marks around the variable :xx?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett - Yes, I tried that.  I get an error stating 'ORA-01821: date format not recognized'.  I've moved the quotation marks to ':xx' and :'xx' - errors both times.

Comment: Does it work if you replace :xx with 'fmMonth ddth, YYYY'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I added a REPLACE function to it.

```
SELECT REPLACE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('04-Jan-2008', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), :xx), '-', ',') AS "Date"
FROM dual;
```

When the variables box pops up, I key in:

```
fmMonth ddth- YYYY
```

It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the item where you enter the date mask is named P1_MASK, you'd have to refer it in your query with notation "& + item_name + .":

```
SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('04-Ene-2008', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '&P1_MASK.') AS "Date"
  FROM dual;
```